# How to send BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast to ONLY your app

Tags: android, shell

This is what I've been trying to do in order to send `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast to my app ONLY:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p my.package.name
```

It gives me this error

```
Error: Unknown option: -p Broadcasting: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2929)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:897)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:321)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:102)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:255)
```

Comment: Are you testing on rooted device?

Comment: @PankajKumar no, its not rooted

Comment: Thats the reason I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that what you need to do in order to send the broadcast just for your app, is simply add the package in the end.

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED my.package.name
```